# Krone vs 110 style punch-down tool / patch panel

Tags: ethernet, cabling

I recently discovered there is a difference between 110 and krone blocks.  When trying to use an (old) cheap model krone style punchdown tool on a patch panel in my new premises I found it very difficult to make the connections, and suspect the ones I made could not be that good.

I then took another punch-down tool, which I suspect is a 110 punch-down tool, and that had no problem making good connections on this patch panel - so my questions -

- To what extent are krone and 110 tools compatible?
- To what extent are krone and 110 panels different (other then the angle the wires go in at?
- Is it likely that the krone punch-down tool is the wrong tool for this job, or just that its damaged/old and out of tolerance?

Comment: My cabling supply company advised that in practice both crone and 110 devices can be punched down with a 110 tool [but the same was not true of the krone tool - so at least not the ones they sell ]